# Bluetooth file transfer limited to specific file extensions?

Tags: bluetooth, 7.0-nougat, file-transfer

I send and receive files via Bluetooth with names that end with ***zip*** and ***txt***, but not ***apk*** or ***dmp***.

Android Nougat

Comment: This is the same question as https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bluetooth-cannot-transfer-files/d3910b3e-d510-4c98-bdb1-fac8064d313c . Those microsoft forums are so flooded by numptys that always answer "restart everything, do random rituals, and avoid interference" and then the threads get locked :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/Constants.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/f6ae67403c20cec20bc8f906411fce4c9ea769f0/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/Constants.java) has the following whitelist of mime types:

```
"image/*",
"video/*",
"audio/*",
"text/x-vcard",
"text/x-vcalendar",
"text/calendar",
"text/plain",
"text/html",
"text/xml",
"application/zip",
"application/vnd.ms-excel",
"application/msword",
"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
"application/pdf",
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
"application/x-hwp",
```

All other types are rejected.

Update: after looking into the sources more. There is a witelist of devices (with 15 sec timeout) with the following comment: "A list of devices that may send files over OPP to this device without user confirmation. Used for connection handover from forex NFC". It looks like these devices can send other mime types. Do not know in which conditions these devices can be added to this whitelist.